# installing numpy but it won't run

Tags: python, numpy, installation

so I've downloaded numpy 1.9.2 from the numpy webpage, unzipped it, and ran the following code

```
C:\python27\python setup.py config
C:\python27\python setup.py install
```

No error messages, it seemed like the instillation went ok. Then I type

```
C:\python27\python
>>> numpy.test()
```

and get an error:

```
NameError: name 'numpy' is not defined
```

type:

```
>>> import numpy as np
```

get an error message:

```
ImportError: No module named numpy
```

Same happens with the python shell when I open it from the python 2.7 folder

I'm guessing I'm missing something really basic here, but what is it?

Comment: Just download Anaconda http://continuum.io/downloads (I don't work for Continuum, it's just by far the easiest way)

Comment: which platform are you using? if on Ubuntu, you should apt-get python-numpy. If on Windows, get a binary installer. If you really want to installl from source code, numpy needs to be build during installation and you will need C and Fortlan compiler properly set up. anaconda or python xy etc will save lots of time for you